# error while running tensorflow object detection api with faster_rcnn_inception_v2_pets model

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow, object-detection, tensorflow-datasets

I have used ssd_mobilenet model for tensorflow object detection API successfully.
When I try to use faster_rcnn_inception_v2_pets it gives bellow error.

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "train.py", line 167, in <module>
    tf.app.run()
  File "/home/chamod/anaconda3/envs/tensorflow-new/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/python/platform/app.py", line 124, in run
    _sys.exit(main(argv))
  File "train.py", line 163, in main
    worker_job_name, is_chief, FLAGS.train_dir)
  File "/home/chamod/champ/new-project-v2/models/object_detection/trainer.py", line 255, in train
    train_config.optimizer)
  File "/home/chamod/champ/new-project-v2/models/object_detection/builders/optimizer_builder.py", line 50, in build
    learning_rate = _create_learning_rate(config.learning_rate)
  File "/home/chamod/champ/new-project-v2/models/object_detection/builders/optimizer_builder.py", line 108, in _create_learning_rate
    learning_rate_sequence)
  File "/home/chamod/champ/new-project-v2/models/object_detection/utils/learning_schedules.py", line 153, in manual_stepping
    tf.constant(range(num_boundaries), dtype=tf.int32),
  File "/home/chamod/anaconda3/envs/tensorflow-new/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/constant_op.py", line 212, in constant
    value, dtype=dtype, shape=shape, verify_shape=verify_shape))
  File "/home/chamod/anaconda3/envs/tensorflow-new/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/tensor_util.py", line 413, in make_tensor_proto
    _AssertCompatible(values, dtype)
  File "/home/chamod/anaconda3/envs/tensorflow-new/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/tensor_util.py", line 328, in _AssertCompatible
    (dtype.name, repr(mismatch), type(mismatch).__name__))
TypeError: Expected int32, got range(0, 3) of type 'range' instead.
```

Is there any specific changes to be made in faster_rcnn_inception_v2_pets.config file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can modify the relevant file as follows.

line 153 : tf.constant(range(num_boundaries), dtype=tf.int32),
to tf.constant(list(range(num_boundaries)), dtype=tf.int32),

this is kind of a python issue since range is not a list.